# SwiftUI: Picker not clickable

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have inserted a `Picker` inside a `Form` and wrapped it with a `NavigationView`. However, the Picker won't display the options. It seems like it clicks (it gets highlighted when I press on it, though in a funky way). I tried using the same code on a separate `View` and it worked. For context, this `View` is a sheet. I tried switching it to a normal `View` but it still doesn't work.

```
@State private var selectedSupplier = 1
var suppliers = ["ABB", "Schneider", "Kahane"]

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                HStack {
                    Text("פריט אינו קיים במלאי")
                }
                
                // section
                // item details
                Section(header: Text("הקלד פרטים")) {
                    HStack {
                        Text("חברה")
                        Spacer()
                        TextField("חברה", text: $brand)
                            .fixedSize()
                    }
                    
                    HStack {
                        Text("סוג פריט")
                        Spacer()
                        TextField("סוג פריט", text: $type)
                            .fixedSize()
                    }
                    
                    HStack {
                        Text("כינוי")
                        Spacer()
                        TextField("כינוי", text: $nickname)
                            .fixedSize()
                    }
                    
                    HStack {
                        Picker(selection: $selectedSupplier, label: Text("ספק")) {
                            //                                ForEach(0 ..<suppliers.count) { index in
                            //                                    Text(self.suppliers[index]).tag(index)
                            //                                }
                            Text("ABB").tag(0)
                            Text("Schneider").tag(1)
                            Text("Kahane").tag(2)
                        }
                    }
                    
                    HStack {
                        Text("ספק")
                        Spacer()
                        TextField("ספק", text: $supplier)
                            .fixedSize()
                    }
                    
                    HStack {
                        // !! should create a dropdown menu
                        Text("כמות במלאי")
                        Spacer()
                        TextField("כמות במלאי", text: $stock)
                            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                            .fixedSize()
                    }
                    
                    HStack {
                        // !! should create a dropdown menu
                        Text("כמות מומלצת")
                        Spacer()
                        TextField("כמות מומלצת", text: $recQuantity)
                            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                            .fixedSize()
                    }
                }

                Section {
                    Picker("Choose a number", selection: $selectedSupplier) {
                        ForEach(0 ..< suppliers.count, id: \.self) { index in
                                            Text(suppliers[index])
                                        }
                                    }
                }
                // section
                // button section
                Section {
                    Button(action: {
                        
                        // Call add data
                        model.addData(id: model.barcodeValue, brand: brand, type: type, stock: Int(stock) ?? 0, nickname: nickname, supplier: supplier, recQuantity: Int(recQuantity) ?? 0)
                        
                        // Clear the text fields
                        brand = ""
                        type = ""
                        stock = ""
                        nickname = ""
                        supplier = ""
                        recQuantity = ""
                        
                        // close down window - return to Scanner View
                        showReg.toggle()
                        
                        
                    }, label: {
                        HStack {
                            Spacer()
                            Text("הוסיף")
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    })
                        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                        .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemBlue))
                    // if any of the three entries (except nickname) is empty, disable button
                        .disabled(type.isEmpty || brand.isEmpty || stock.isEmpty)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("הוספת פריט למלאי")
            // hide the keyboard if user clicks outside the form
            .onTapGesture {
                hideKeyboard()
            }
            .environment(\.layoutDirection, .rightToLeft)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See if you can post a self-contained example, as small as possible, that builds and runs and shows the problem; that will make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: It seems like the problem is the `.onTapGesture`, it's interfering with the `Picker`. Any ideas on how to circumvent this?

Comment: Very hard to say. It doesn't build as-is, and my guesses about how to get it to build are probably wrong, including my guess about what `hideKeyboard()` is doing inside `.onTapGesture`. I'm not sure whether I'm actually reproducing your bug or just getting artifacts due to my guesses

Comment: Also, which `Picker` is failing? Is it the one without `tags`?

Comment: Both `Picker`s.

Comment: In case it helps you, [this example](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/pickers-in-forms) works great.

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where my picker suddenly decided to stop working. I was at a loss, until I realized that it was the .onTapGesture that I added to resign the keyboard.

```
VStack {
    ...
    Picker() {
        ...
    }
    
    HStack {
        Text()
        TextField()
    }
    //Placing the .onTapGesture here doesn't interfere with the Picker, but it doesn't get the functionality you'd like, either
}
//The code below interferes with the ability to tap on the Picker
.onTapGesture {
_ in UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
}
```

Comment: You ever find a work around for this?

Comment: Kind of, not really. My view is embedded in a ScrollView, with buttons to Cancel (dismiss the view) or Add (dismiss the view and perform action based on the input). The buttons move to the top of the keyboard and leave plenty of space for the user to scroll the view and interact with the form. Since the view is a quick-add type of view, this works gracefully enough. I.e., if the user isn't typing, then it's time to dismiss the view anyways, in my case.

Comment: Ahh Gotcha, Thank you for the response - appreciate it!

Comment: Found this issue in several cases. I don't know why the tab gesture bleeds all the way to the view container which holds the picker. imho even though this is not a zstack, the container view should act like it. So if i put a tap gesture on the container and i click the picker, it shouldn't bleed past it